# aws s3 cp to bucket returns error code 1 on large files

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

When copying a large file to s3, I get an error code 1 from aws cp.

```
$ aws s3 cp --version
aws-cli/1.5.5 Python/2.6.9 Linux/3.0.101-0.46-default
$ aws s3 cp source-file target-on-s3
(screen output...)
Completed 1 of 858 part(s) with 1 file(s) remaining
...
Completed 116 of 858 part(s) with 1 file(s) remaining
$ echo $?
1
```

On retry, it picks up some more remaining "parts". This goes on until the file is fully uploaded.

What causes this behavior on `aws s3 cp`? Am I missing some `cp` options? File size is in excess of 20GB which I had thought was puny by S3 standards. And I am inside the AWS cloud.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade your version of AWS CLI (latest I see is 1.7.20).

aws s3 cp local_file_name.csv  s3://bucket_name/folder/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Thanks. `--expected-size` is not necessary when uploading from file system because cp can stat it.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that part - "--expected-size" is useful only for streams larger than 5GB.